# Ubuntu, Bash, awk, regular expressions -> find all the [numbers] in text file and print them

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I want to find each number in "[]" brackets, and print all their appearances (line numbers) in text file.

For example I got text file like this:

```
texttexttext[1] textetxtetete[2]
[1]textextetetete[3]
texttexttext[2]
texttexttext
text[3]text[1]
```

And the output should be this :

```
[1] = lines : 1 2 5
[2] = lines : 1 3
[3] = lines : 2 5
```

This is what I've done so far :

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | awk -F'[/[/] ]' '{     #[] as file separators
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)             #for every part of line
  {
  if ($i ~ "[0-9]+")            #if its number
    {
      #save it somehow
    }
}}'
```

The script finds the desired numbers, but now I want to save it, and its line number (NR variable) in some simple way. Should I try something with arrays? I would need at least two-dimensional arrays, but they are a bit problematic in bash. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: `awk` doesn't support true multidimensional arrays, but `gawk` does (albeit with a few kinks).  Unless you want to string multiple commands together, you'll need to use something with sane multidimensional array support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using awk (and a one-dimensional array)

```
awk -F"[\],\[]" '{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
  if ($i ~ "[0-9]+")
    {
      arr[$i]=arr[$i]" "NR
    }
   }
} 
END{for(i in arr){print "["i"] lines : " arr[i]}}' t.txt
```

Output:

```
[1] lines :  1 2 5
[2] lines :  1 3
[3] lines :  2 5
```

Remark:
The regex `[0-9]+` matches also strings containing characters (e.g., `4a`). If your input file contains something like `[45a]` and if you want to exclude this, then change your regex to `^[0-9]+$`.

Comment: Wow. Slow clap.. You get an upvote, its out of order, but who cares, im going to save this!

Comment: @JavierBuzzi: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation using gawk's `FPAT` and `sorted_in`:

```
    BEGIN { # define fields via FPAT and sort order 
        FPAT="\[[0-9]+\]" 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        }
    { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) occ[ $i ] = occ[ $i ] " " FNR }

    END { for( i in occ ) printf( "%s = lines : %s\n", i, occ[ i ] ) }
```